How to use a different source for a cargo dependency under miri
My project depends on the bitvec crate (crate knowlege not required for question).
This crate is unfortunately not very actively maintained and has a few
issues under miri.
A gracious soul has fixed the miri related issues (and made a PR that is sitting stale).
In order to use miri on my project I tried to use this patched version,
but I did not want to depend on some github repo for the release version,
so I tried the following in my Cargo.toml
[target.'cfg(miri)'.dependencies]
bitvec = { git = "https://github.com/djkoloski/bitvec.git", branch = "fix_miri" }

[target.'cfg(not(miri))'.dependencies]
bitvec = "1.0.1"

This unfortunately gave me the following error:
~$ MIRIFLAGS="-Zmiri-tree-borrows" cargo +nightly miri test 
thread 'main' panicked at src/tools/miri/cargo-miri/src/util.rs:235:80:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: CargoMetadata { stderr: "error: failed to load manifest for workspace member `<myproject>`\nreferenced by workspace at `<myworkspace>/Cargo.toml`\n\nCaused by:\n  failed to parse manifest at `<myproject>/Cargo.toml`\n\nCaused by:\n  Dependency 'bitvec' has different source paths depending on the build target. Each dependency must have a single canonical source path irrespective of build target.\n" }
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

Is there a way to only use this dependency under miri?

Why would you want UB in your production code? Miri only complains about UB that it detects in the code it runs.

@cafce25 : The issues that miri detect with this crate are things that (afaik) LLVM currently doesn't
optimize based on (it nags about pointer provenance when casting through a usize for example). This should not cause issues in practice, so I'd rather not depend on some random github repo if possible.

Using exposed provenance is not UB, Miri complains about it because it makes it unable to detect UB precisely. You can silence it with -Zmiri-permissive-provenance. If Miri complains about actual UB, even if LLVM doesn't optimize based on it today, you are better off depending on some random GitHub repo than depending on this.

@ChayimFriedman: Tree Borrows does not support integer-to-pointer casts, and is hence not compatible with permissive provenance. I also do not see how this is relevant to the question?

@ChrisB Tree borrows is compatible with provenance exposure (aka. integer to pointer as casts). Every model will have to be, since this operation is stable (but what it means exactly is fuzzy). Miri is not able to detect UB with those casts, which is why it produces a warning (that you can silence). This isn't a direct answer to the question (which is why I posted this in a comment) but it is still useful feedback about your underlying problem.

@ChayimFriedman: calling miri with MIRIFLAGS="-Zmiri-tree-borrows -Zmiri-permissive-provenance" gives you an error literally saying
fatal error: Tree Borrows does not support integer-to-pointer casts, and is hence not compatible with permissive provenance,
so I guess you would have to debate that one with Ralf Jung, not me ;).
But I appreciate the attempt to help, sorry for being snarky.

OK this is weird :) I'm pretty sure it will have to adapt before (if) becoming the official model, but for now I guess it indeed doesn't support them. Is the code not Stacked Borrows compatible?

@ChayimFriedman: No unfortunately the bitvec crate fails to pass that, I guess in the long term I will replace that dependency or fork it or something, but I just hoped there would be a decent intermediate solution here.

Sounds like a potential use case for a multiple location dependency.  Or else you could rename one of the dependencies and select which to use via conditional compilation.

I ended up using the following workaround,
thanks for @eggyal
for pointing me in the right direction with his comment on renaming dependencies.

Cargo.toml
[target.'cfg(miri)'.dependencies]
bitvec_miri = { git = "https://github.com/djkoloski/bitvec.git", branch = "fix_miri", package = "bitvec" }

[target.'cfg(not(miri))'.dependencies]
bitvec_non_miri = { version = "1.0.1", package = "bitvec" }

src/lib.rs (Root of your project)
#[cfg(miri)]
extern crate bitvec_miri as bitvec;

#[cfg(not(miri))]
extern crate bitvec_non_miri as bitvec;


If rust-analyzer is mad at you,
add the following to your .vscode/settings.json:
"rust-analyzer.cargo.cfgs": {
    "debug_assertions": null
}

As described here, they enable the miri configuration variable by default, which
diverges from the actual build flags. Specifying this setting should override the default.

I'd probably prefer extern crate bitvec_non_miri as bitvec; in your root module, and then you can just carry on using bitvec throughout your code as usual.
